# ¿Cómo cambiar el color de la barra de menús en Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Mi sistema operativo es Windows 10, y utilizo Eclipse Oxygen y he habilitado el Dark theme. El problema es que es muy molesto que la barra de menú no haya cambiado de color y me gustaría saber como puedo hacerlo. Es decir como hacer que también sea negra, para que sea acorde con el tema. Gracias.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -3):

Ve al apartado de Window > Preferences > General > Appearance > Theme. Y lo cambia a Light (El que viene por defecto o el que tu elijas).

Comment: Creo que lo que quiere es cambiar la barra de menú y no volver al mismo tema que tenía

Comment: Bueno entonces tendria que buscar en tutoriales como cambiar la parte superior de todas las barras de las ventenas de windows, no puedes camiar la de solo un programa Windows no te da esa opcion, pero la verdad nunca he cambiado eso, yo uso linux y la verdad que esas cosas en linux es bastante facil modificarlas

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios. Es cierto, en linux es bastante fácil modificarlo todo, de hecho por cuestiones éticas y de personalización me costo mucho decidirme por Windows, pero por motivos de  problemas al instalar ciertos programas, me vi en la necesidad de instalar Windows. Sé que el color de la barra de título es asignada por el sistema operativo. Pero mi pregunta es por la barra de menús, es decir la que contiene las opciones de Archivo y editar, conservando el tema dark. Gracias.